# How to I edit my remote FTP servers on an existing Web Storm project?

Tags: webstorm

I have a project created in Web Storm and running with a remote FTP server configured.

I would like to add another FTP server, one for the staging\testing and one for production, how do I do this?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/deployment.html

Comment: @CrazyCoder Totally correct, do you want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` | `Settings` | [Deployment](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/deployment.html).

Comment: I approve of your brevity.